# C# nullable not detecting issue correctly?

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm working on migrating a project to support C# 8.0 nullable but I ran into a situation where it looks like Visual Studio isn't detecting a null value correctly. If you look at the code below in the TestClass constructor the Console.WriteLine method will throw a NullReferenceException because this.Value is null and hasn't been assigned yet. There are no warnings or errors from VS though, it thinks everything is fine here. Am I missing something, shouldn't VS be warning about this? The value is definitely null here. Thanks!

```
#nullable enable

namespace TestNullable
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass test = new TestClass("MyString");
        }

        public class TestClass
        {
            private readonly string Value;

            public TestClass(string value)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(this.Value.Length.ToString());
                this.Value = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It's good, but it's not *that* good"

Comment: It looks like a potential bug with the nullable analyzer... basically since `Value` is non-nullable, it doesn't check for it being null/uninitialized on that line, but instead just checks to see if `Value` is initialized *anywhere*.

Comment: I opened a case with Microsoft, hopefully it's something they'll get fixed up soon. Thanks everyone!